# Deploy all artifacts to Artifactory with jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

We have a product which is running with multiple microservers(jar) . these are all maven projects . as part of CI/CD pipeline first i have created maven jobs for each microservice . these jobs creates JAR files . I want to deploy all these jar files to aftifactory after all jobs successfully completed making jar files .

Artifactory plugin provides feature as after JAR creation we can deploy to artifactory . But problem with this approach is , it deploy to artifactory after each jobs build successful .
  Product is stable after all jobs successfully completed . So with this acknowledgement i have to start deployment .

```
node {
    def server
    def buildInfo
    def rtMaven

    stage ('Clone') {
        git url: 'https://github.com/jfrogdev/project-examples.git'
    }

    stage ('Artifactory configuration') {
        // Obtain an Artifactory server instance, defined in Jenkins --> Manage:
        server = Artifactory.server SERVER_ID

        rtMaven = Artifactory.newMavenBuild()
        rtMaven.tool = MAVEN_TOOL // Tool name from Jenkins configuration
        rtMaven.deployer releaseRepo: 'libs-release-local', snapshotRepo: 'libs-snapshot-local', server: server
        rtMaven.resolver releaseRepo: 'libs-release', snapshotRepo: 'libs-snapshot', server: server
        rtMaven.deployer.deployArtifacts = false // Disable artifacts deployment during Maven run

        buildInfo = Artifactory.newBuildInfo()
    }

    stage ('Test') {
        rtMaven.run pom: 'maven-example/pom.xml', goals: 'clean test'
    }

    stage ('Install') {
        rtMaven.run pom: 'maven-example/pom.xml', goals: 'install', buildInfo: buildInfo
    }

    stage ('Deploy') {
        rtMaven.deployer.deployArtifacts buildInfo
    }

    stage ('Publish build info') {
        server.publishBuildInfo buildInfo
    }
}
```

above pipeline syntax clones the code from git and creates package and deploy it . But i no need clone and creating package . I just need to deploy which are already build by other jobs . Please help with this

Comment: If you just need to deploy, have you considered using Artifactory's CLI or REST API? you will not be able to get the build info published to Artifactory that way, but you can upload any file to your Artifactory repos easily.

Comment: Yes. If we use REST API , we are not able to get build info . I am going ahead with a Artifactory plugin only . Deploying into artifactory after each microservice build completed

Answer (score 0):

I believe your approach is wrong: you look at pipelines as if they were jobs, but in reality a pipeline is a collection of jobs where each pipeline step can be associated to a series of jobs. Each pipeline step correlates to a specific "phase".
Once you get into this perspective, you either step into the pipeline approach, migrating the other jobs into the pipeline, or just use the old style and define a deploy job which gets executed after the jobs you already have...

I hope that does make sense because this is my understanding of pipelines; I'm new at using those as well.